# Trying to plot a time course, 2 factors, 1 response variable with standard error bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

As title states, I'm trying to plot a time course of a response variable (that has 2 factors), working environment based in Rstudio.
I'm working off a data frame that's already in long format. Something like:

```
|Week| Factor1 | Factor2| Response|
 
  1     Sunny     High      2.0
  1     Sunny     High      3.5
  1     Rainy     Low       2.5
  1     Rainy     Low       1.5
  2     Sunny     High      42.5
  2     Sunny     High      435
  2     Rainy     Low       44.5
  2     Rainy     Low       42.5
  3     Sunny     High      80.5
  3     Sunny     High      89.5
  3     Rainy     Low       88.5
  3     Rainy     Low       87.5
```

I would like to do a time course with this data frame, but haven't had much success as I cannot figure out how to make ggplot2 plot the Response line as a variable responding to the combination of Factors.

I've sort of done it with geom_smooth(se=FALSE) instead of geom_line. Doing so with the se=FALSE argument removes the confidence interval bounds.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  unite(Factor, c(Factor1, Factor2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week, Response, group = Factor, color = Factor)) +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

or

```
df <- unite(df,col='Combined Factors',c(Factor1,Factor2),sep='-',remove=FALSE)
    df %>% 
      group_by(Week,`Combined Factors`) %>% 
      mutate(avg_Response=mean(Response),se_Response=sd(Response)/sqrt(4)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(Week, Response,group=`Combined Factors`,color=`Combined Factors`))+
      geom_smooth(se=FALSE) %>% 
      {.} -> Line_plot_Response
```

[This creates the output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mPS7.png)

now for adding in error bars at each y-axis point

so far, I have only succeeded somewhat in plotting the line graph, but cannot make R recognise  my factor 1 and factor 2 as a group and fix the standard error to it. I've tried creating another dataframe and used the summarise.data function but the resulting graph is just a hot mess as the standard error bars are all over the graph and not fixed to each plotted point.. I can do all of this in excel to be honest, but would like to do it in R so that I can improve my coding understanding. I don't understandddddd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, for each combination of `Factor1` and `Factor2` you want to calculate the mean value of `Response` for each week, and use these points as the co-ordinates for a line plot. You would also like to draw error bars around these points.

The sample data you have provided isn't ideal to demonstrate this, but the code that gives the result as I have described it above would be something like:

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Week, Response, group = interaction(Factor1, Factor2),
             color = interaction(Factor1, Factor2))) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'line', fun = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom = 'point', fun = mean, color = 'black') +
  stat_summary(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.1, alpha = 0.8, size = 0.3) +
  labs(color = 'Conditions') +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Allan. Would you mind if I asked you a few more questions regarding the solution?